# How to plot k-means clustering results in an ordered way

Tags: python, seaborn, data-science

I am using k-mans clustering as a means of customer and product segmentation.  I found a function on stack that takes the cluster results and reorders them based on the average value of a target value in the dataframe.  This seems to be working quite well but in order to plot the results I am first creating a string column in the data frame based on the ordered clustering to prevent seaborn from creating bins in the hue labels.  The first problem I ran into was that while the plot and labels were being generated as intended the legend was out of order.  I added a hue order but the ledgend becomes fixed to this order so changing the value of K makes the legend confusing.  I added a function to address this problem as well and everything seems to be working as intended but I would like to know if there are any better ways of achiving this.  I will place the related code blocks bellow.

```
#function for ordering cluster numbers
def order_cluster(cluster_field_name, target_field_name,df,ascending):
    new_cluster_field_name = 'new_' + cluster_field_name
    df_new = df.groupby(cluster_field_name)[target_field_name].mean().reset_index()
    df_new = df_new.sort_values(by=target_field_name,ascending=ascending).reset_index(drop=True)
    df_new['index'] = df_new.index
    df_final = pd.merge(df,df_new[[cluster_field_name,'index']], on=cluster_field_name)
    df_final = df_final.drop([cluster_field_name],axis=1)
    df_final = df_final.rename(columns={"index":cluster_field_name})
    return df_final


#adding column to dataframe based on clustering 
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(data[['ORDERS_PLACED','UNITS_SOLD','AVG_UNIT_PRICE','TOTAL_SALES']])
data['Rank'] = kmeans.predict(data[['ORDERS_PLACED','UNITS_SOLD','AVG_UNIT_PRICE','TOTAL_SALES']])

#ordering the results
data = order_cluster('Rank','TOTAL_SALES',data,True)

top = data['Rank'].max()

#adding string column to dataframe
data['Rank_ID'] = [('Group_A' if x == top else
                    ('Group_B' if x == top - 1 else
                     ('Group_C' if x == top - 2 else
                      ('Group_D' if x == top - 3 else
                       ('Group_E' if x == top - 4 else
                        ('Group_F' if x == top - 5 else
                         ('Group_G' if x == top - 6 else
                          ('Group_H' if x == top - 7 else
                           ('Group_I' if x == top - 8 else
                            ('Group_J' if x == top - 9 else 'Group_Z')))))))))
                   ) for x in data['Rank']]



#function to build the plot legend values
def build_legend(k_value):
    if k_value == 0:
        legend = ['Group_A']
    elif k_value == 1:
        legend = ['Group_A','Group_B']
    elif k_value == 2:
        legend = ['Group_A','Group_B','Group_C']
    elif k_value == 3:
        legend = ['Group_A','Group_B','Group_C','Group_D']
    elif k_value == 4:
        legend = ['Group_A','Group_B','Group_C','Group_D','Group_E']
    elif k_value == 5:
        legend = ['Group_A','Group_B','Group_C','Group_D','Group_E','Group_F']
    elif k_value == 6:
        legend = ['Group_A','Group_B','Group_C','Group_D','Group_E','Group_F','Group_G']
    elif k_value == 7:
        legend = ['Group_A','Group_B','Group_C','Group_D','Group_E','Group_F','Group_G','Group_H']
    elif k_value == 8:
        legend = ['Group_A','Group_B','Group_C','Group_D','Group_E','Group_F','Group_G','Group_H','Group_I']
    elif k_value == 9:
        legend = ['Group_A','Group_B','Group_C','Group_D','Group_E','Group_F','Group_G','Group_H','Group_I','Group_J']
    else:
        legend = ['Group_A','Group_B','Group_C','Group_D','Group_E','Group_F','Group_G','Group_H','Group_I','Group_J','Group_Z']
    return legend






#plotting the results
orderHue = build_legend(top)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))

plot = sns.scatterplot(x='ORDERS_PLACED', y='TOTAL_SALES', hue='Rank_ID', size='Rank_ID', 
                       hue_order=orderHue,  size_order=orderHue, data=report, ax=ax)

ytick = plot.get_yticks()
plot.set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x) for x in ytick])

plot.set_title('80/20 Customer Segmentation Using K-Means Clustering, Plot on Orders Placed & Total Sales',fontsize=12)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)

plt.show(plot)
```

This seems like a lot of code to achive what might be quite simple.

Here is a quick sample of the data as requested,

```
CUSTOMER_ID  ORDERS_PLACED  UNITS_SOLD   AVG_UNIT_PRICE   TOTAL_SALES
A            2              59           21553.9          1271680 
B            106            184          6295.9           1158445.7
C            13             78           14290            1114620
D            43             2034         245.38           499102
E            53             582          760.92           442856 
F            1              6            15000            90000 
G            3              60           967              58020
H            1              1            1807             1807
```

Comment: Could you show a sample dataset for us to play with?

Comment: Sure.  I added a small sample from my import. It isnt normalized but I dont think that should matter for an example.  The full data set has right under 300 rows